# Why isn't number of loops included in the EMF equation?

Tags: inductance, emf

The following is a snapshot from (http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/inductance.html).

I understand the first equation which relates inductance, number of wraps, and current. But since EMF is equal to the derivative of flux with respect to time. Therefore if we take the first equation, solve for flux, and differentiate, we should still have the number of loops as a term in the equation.

Why is this not the case?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[It is there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction#Quantitative), where you find it depends on how you define the flux. If you consider \$\phi\$ to be the flux through a single loop, then the definition of the EMF must be N times the single loop flux. If you define \$\phi\$ to be the flux from all loops, you've already accounted for N in computing the total flux and it doesn't show up in the EMF definition. In both cases, you get the same answer.

Mathematically, this could be written as (where \$\phi\$ is the single loop flux and \$\psi\$ is the total flux):

\begin{gather}
\frac{d \psi}{dt} = \frac{d (N \phi)}{dt} = N \frac{d \phi}{dt} = -\textrm{EMF}
\end{gather}